# Python, replace digits with alphabet in string

Tags: python

What is proper method to replace digits to alphabet which are similar to alphabet in Python?

Example:

`"Hell0 my name 1s J0hn"` -> `"Hello my name is John"`

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: Have you tried [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) ?

Comment: yes I have tried replace, but just thinking is replace is the best method for this task?

Comment: You can use `s.replace('0', 'o')` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to either precisely define a mapping of digits which you believe are similar to characters, or, if you want to do it a hard way, develop a learning algorithm to find similarities, and then substitute them. Computers aren't really good at understanding abstract concepts.

Once you have a mapping, it can easily be done -

```
input_string = "Hell0 my name 1s J0hn"
mapping = {'0': 'o'} #...
for key, value in mapping.items():
    input_string = input_string.replace(key, value)
```

Comment: For me is enough list of digits similar to characters "0" -> 0, "I" -> 1, "B" -> 8

Comment: @Streem Then, the best option is create a dictionary.

Comment: Manel Fornos, please could you explain what do you mean to create a dictionary?

Comment: @Streem like I have created mapping in my answer. Hashes are called dictionaries in python

Comment: Thank you all answers seems a pretty good code. Thanks for all.

Comment: @hspandher, you should change your mapping to something meaningful, mapping `"0"` to `"0"` is not really useful.

Comment: @Christian, oops. I have changed it. Anyway, it was still demonstrating my point.

Comment: @Christian I liked your answer though. I had never heard of str.maketrans, probably because it's python3 specific, I guess.

Comment: @hspandher: it is quite useful for this kind of tasks. I just saw that you should also correct `{"0":"o"}`, since you want a dict, not a set.

Comment: @Christian, me and my typos. Thanks again. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 4):

This calls for [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
>>> leettext = "Hell0 my name 1s J0hn"
>>> leettext.translate(str.maketrans({"0":"o", "1":"i"}))
'Hello my name is John'
```

Notice that this will not distinguish between lower and upper characters, since that information is not available in leetspeak.

Doing some small tests the `translate` scales better when the dictionary grows, since you iterate over the whole string for each mapping with the other `replace()` solutions.

Comment: nice to see a non-`replace` answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use `replace`, e.g (edit after @Dmitry's remark):

```
s = "Hell0 my name 1s J0hn"
r =  [[0,'o'], [1, 'i']]
for e in r:
    s = s.replace(str(e[0]),str(e[1]))
print s
```

Output: `Hello my name is John`

NB: They are probably more efficient way (without the for)

Comment: Why do you use `numpy.array` for the simple task?